# snmp issue:Two similar servers returning different output

Tags: linux, snmp

I am having issue with SNMP OID's .
I have two similar servers (hardware and software) Which is Dell server with RHEL 5.3 X86_64. The issue is when I run the `SNMPWALK` for one server it shows proper data while the other server returns

> No Such Instance currently exists at this OID

Both have net-snmp version as:  5.3.2.2

OID seems to be custom and only for Dell machines "`1.3.6.1.4.1.674`" (`SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.674`), but both machines are Dell based and follow the same architecture and components.
Can someone trace on cause of this issue?

Comment: Any differences in configuration?

Comment: Apparently one server has that MIB installed, the other doesn't. Try comparing the installed softwarepackages on both of them. It is likely one of them has more and/or different packages installed.

Comment: Thank you guys .I had found the cause .It was from Dell open manage software .Dataeng must be enabled with snmp .